# Fastest way to load_model for inference in Tensorflow Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I’m trying to quickly load a model from disk to make predictions in a REST API. The *tf.keras.models.load_model* method takes ~1s to load so it’s too slow for what I’m trying to do. Compile flag is set to false.

What is the fastest way to load a model from disk for inference only in Tensorflow/Keras?

Is there any way to persist the model in memory between requests?

I tried caching but pickle deserialisation is very expensive and adds ~1.2s. I suspect the built-in Keras load model does some sort of serialisation too, which seems to be the killer.

PD: I'm aware of TFX but feels like an overkill as I've already set up a REST API. Predictions are fast, just need to quickly load the model from disk or persist in memory between requests.

Thanks in advance,
Joan

Answer (score 0):

Doink! I had a bit of a brain fart moment just there so in case you have it too, here is a solution that does the job.

Just load the model when you start the server so all request can use the model.

Comment: that works if you have one model, that is being used frequently. if you have many different models, used infrequently, you might have a bottleneck in model-loading. that is why tf-serving is so nice, it has features like warming up models and keeping them in memory, if there is space ... too bad tf-serving bugs out with my efficientnet and convnext ...